# Share title image and description in facebook

Tags: facebook, share, blogger

I'm trying to customize how a blog share looks in facebook, so far I add this as recommended in facebook

```
<meta content='0how' property='og:site_name'/>
<meta content='0how' property='og:title'/>
<meta content='0how' property='og:description'/>
<meta content='image.jpg'/>
<meta content='http://0how.blogspot.com/' property='og:url'/>
<meta content='blog' property='og:type'/>
```

I want this settings just for the main page, but the problem is that this settings also apply when sharing an individual post. Is there a way disable it for posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to set up open graph data for a blogger blog . refer this [tutorial](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1399895-adding-open-graph-tags-using-blogger) to set appropriate titles for individual posts of your website . Also refer this [tutorial](http://unidigadv.blogspot.in/2014/09/adding-open-graph-protocol-ogp-tags-to.html) for an in depth explanation

```
<!-- Open Graph Meta Tags BEGIN -->
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
  <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
</b:if>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
  <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
</b:if>
<!-- Open Graph Meta Tags END -->
```